# Retrieving an autoincrement value after INSERT duplicate key

Tags: mysql, sql-insert, auto-increment, myisam, last-insert-id

I have a mySQL 5.7 **myISAM** table T:

```
Col  Key    Other
A    PRI   
B           autoincrement
C
```

I want to perform the following operation:
Given the values x and y

- if there is already a row where A=x, give me back B
- otherwise, insert a row where A=x and C=y, and give me back B

The simplest way of doing this seems to be

```
SELECT B FROM T WHERE A=x;
if the row doesn't exist,
INSERT INTO T SET A=x, C=y;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

However, this is non-atomic, meaning I would need to implement some sort of locking.

I was hoping I could use

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO T SET A=x, C=y;
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

but `LAST_INSERT_ID()` doesn't return B when the INSERT is ignored on a duplicate key.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this atomically, without locking?

Comment: Are you working with a data that already exists in your table? The insert ignore is just inserting a record with a primary key and skip if primary key exists in your working table.

Comment: @reds - I hoped that it might return the auto-increment field even in that circumstance. But on reflection, it seems like this would require a trip to the data row, which the IGNORE allowed us to bypass.

Comment: Stop using MyISAM; switch to InnoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it with `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, since that's only set when something is actually inserted and a new ID is assigned. You'll have to select the key you just inserted:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO T SET a=x, C=y;
SELECT B FROM T WHERE a = x;
```

Comment: Yes. I'm guessing here, but it seems like mySQL would first consult its primary key index and discover the duplicate key violation, without ever fetching the data row where the auto-increment value is.

Comment: They're two separate queries. When it discovers the duplication in the `INSERT` it does nothing, then `SELECT` returns that row's value from `b`.

Comment: I was unclear: I agree with your solution, and I'm speculating why my original idea (that `LAST_INSERT_ID()` might work even if `INSERT` discovered a duplication) would not work. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

See the example of how to use `id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id)` in the `UPDATE` part of IODKU.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html